# Как упростить условие?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такое условие, для воспроизведения звука при смене картинки:

```
if  ((id == 100) && (type == 'off') && (arrSound['v1'] != 1)) {
    ion.sound.play('off');
    arrSound['v1'] = 1;
} else if ((id == 100) && (type == 'on') && (arrSound['v1'] == 1)) {
    ion.sound.play('on');
    arrSound['v1'] = 0;
}
```

Как можно упростить это условие, или сделать короче?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (id == 100)
{
    arrSound['v1'] = arrSound['v1'] != 1 ? 1 : 0;
    ion.sound.play(type);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (id == 100)
{
    if ((type == 'off') && (arrSound['v1'] != 1))
    {
        ion.sound.play('off');
        arrSound['v1'] = 1;
    }

    if ((type == 'on') && (arrSound['v1'] == 1))
    {
        ion.sound.play('on');
        arrSound['v1'] = 0;
    }   
}
```